# How to access the nested key value pairs in a Json in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop

I have returned the response from the backend as nested hash map that is a hash map within a hash map :

hmap.put(l,hmaps); //hmap within hmap

return new ResponseEntity(Collections.singletonMap("responsive",hmap), HttpStatus.OK);

My response from Backend looks like the following:

email1 and email2 are the keys of a hash map and the subparts are the keys and values pair for the nested hash map.

```
responsive: {email2: {,…},…}
 email1: {sub3: "Hi Subpart 3", sub4: "Hi Subpart 4",…}
  sub1: "Hi subpart 1"
  sub2: "Hi subpart 2"
  sub3: "Hi Subpart 3"
  sub4: "Hi subpart 4"
 email2: {,…}
  sub7: "Hi Subpart 7"
  sub8: "Hi Subpart 8"

I have accessed the email1 and email2 in the following fashion :

 Object.keys(emails.responsive).forEach(e => {
          let ref = this.dialog.open(emaildialog, {    
             data: emails.responsive[e],
             width: "600px",
             height: "600px",

            } 
          );

        });
```

Now I need to access the subpart of each Email type, but I am not able to do so.

Comment: it sounds like it needs to be accessed just like regular object- `e.something`, but the structure of the object coming back from the server is really unclear. whats inside email1 or email2? are all the emails and subs found inside the "responsive" object, or on the same level as it? should really clarify more what you get from the server

Comment: please post a valid json output here ( look into network tab and paste the response   here, you may have copied it from console   )

Comment: I have edited the question with more information, Hope it helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If structure data is:

```
 emails = {
  email1: {
    sub1: "Hi subpart 1",
    sub2: "Hi subpart 2",
    sub3: "Hi Subpart 3",
    sub4: "Hi subpart 4",
  },
  email2: {
    sub5: "Hi subpart 5",
    sub6: "Hi subpart 6",
    sub7: "Hi Subpart 7",
    sub8: "Hi subpart 8",
  }
}
```

You can access the subpart of each Email type:

```
Object.keys(emails).forEach(e => {
  Object.keys(emails[e]).forEach(item => {
    console.log(emails[e][item]);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

for below JSON, or further nested JSON:

```
    Obj : {
      email1: {
        sub1: "Hi subpart 1",
        sub2: "Hi subpart 2",
        sub3: "Hi Subpart 3",
        sub4: "Hi subpart 4",
      },
      email2: {
        sub5: "Hi subpart 5",
        sub6: "Hi subpart 6",
        sub7: "Hi Subpart 7",
        sub8: "Hi subpart 8",
      }
    }
```

or

```
    Obj : {
      email1: {
        sub1: "Hi subpart 1",
        sub2: "Hi subpart 2",
        sub3: "Hi Subpart 3",
        sub4: {
            sub41: "Hi Subpart 4",
            sub42: "Hi Subpart 42"
        },
      },
      email2: {
        sub5: "Hi subpart 5",
        sub6: "Hi subpart 6",
        sub7: "Hi Subpart 7",
        sub8: "Hi subpart 8",
      }
    }
```

try below:

```
  function getObjectKeyValue(obj, key) {
      if (typeof(obj) === "string")
        console.log(key + " " + obj);

      else for (key in obj)
        getObjectKeyValue(obj[key], key)
    }
```

getObjectKeyValue(Obj)